# Billing Agreement Id or transaction Id is not valid

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I have a billing agreement id, which I used for capture transaction.

But getting an error "11451: Billing Agreement Id or transaction Id is not valid".

I am passing below request to paypal.

```
 [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
 [DoReferenceTransaction] => Array
    (
        [REFERENCEID] => <<B-BillingAgreementID>>
        [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
        [AMT] => 0.01
        [INVNUM] => 100000498
        [NOTIFYURL] => http://mystore.com/paypal/ipn/
        [CURRENCYCODE] => CAD
        [METHOD] => DoReferenceTransaction
        [VERSION] => 72.0
        [USER] => ****
        [PWD] => ****
        [SIGNATURE] => ****
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
    )
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the billing agreement (BA) Id. The API shows that you are trying to create a Reference Transaction against live API endpoint https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp. Kindly check whether you are passing Live BA ID or Sandbox BA ID.